# How to play the output of OpenCV to Kivy VideoPlayer or any other player?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, opencv3.0, dlib

I want to make a face detection video player. I have the following dlib code for face detection. I want the output of the OpenCV video to be played on my Kivy Video Player. Can anyone tell me how can I do it?

**main.py**

```
from detect_face import FaceDetector
import cv2
import argparse
from imutils import resize




# PROTOTXT_PATH = './models/MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt'
# CAFFE_MODEL_PATH = './models/MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel'
# person.detect_(image)
# image = person.display_person_nn(image)
# person = PersonDetector(0.4, PROTOTXT_PATH, CAFFE_MODEL_PATH)




if __name__ == '__main__':

    #ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    #ap.add_argument('-v', '--video', required=True)
    #args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    #video_files_path = args['video']
    video_files_path = "test.mp4"

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_files_path)
    # Initialised a face detector
    face = FaceDetector()
    while True:

        success, image = cap.read()

        if success:
            image = resize(image, width=512)
            f = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
            #Do something
            print(f)

            _ = face.detect_(image)
            face.display_face(image)


            cv2.imshow('', image)
            k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
            if k == 27:
                break
        else:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()
```

There's a separate detect_face.py file for the actual face detection code.
Please tell me if you require the kivy videoplayer code too.

Comment: The main reason why I want to do that is to seek through the face detection output video using the kivy VideoPlayer.

Comment: you do not have a video as an output, you have Mat <> `image` as an output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have a video as output but some arrays that represent an image,so we can place those arrays as `Texture`, and then set it to an `Image`.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2

class KivyCV(Image):
    def __init__(self, capture, fps, **kwargs):
        Image.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.capture = capture
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / fps)

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("lbpcascade_frontalface.xml")
            faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
                gray,
                scaleFactor=1.1,
                minNeighbors=5,
                minSize=(30, 30),
                flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
            )

            for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

            buf = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            # display image from the texture
            self.texture = image_texture


class OpenCVApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture("/path/of/filename_or_device")
        my_camera = KivyCV(capture=self.capture, fps=60)
        return my_camera

    def on_stop(self):
        self.capture.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    OpenCVApp().run()
```

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/ff74dbdad68d120351862da98bba02e9).

Comment: Thanks! I tried the face detection code. It's working perfectly using Kivy. To add to the functions, I want to add buttons to pause/play/stop and a seek bar in my player to seek through the video as the face detection continuously runs on the video. I tried to embed the VideoPlayer code inside the build function but to no avail. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: @Dawnstrider You can not use VideoPlayer, I think you can try it a bit more, these last requirements were not in your question, and if you still can not do it then at that moment I will be happy to help you. If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour]

Comment: I mentioned the details in the comment. Is there any alternative then to open the video with Kivy and create a GUI to stop/play/pause and seek?